# How to refresh other html files when a function is called in one html file.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I need some help.

I have angularjs application. It has 2 tabs. The first one is for viewing items and the second tab is for adding items. I want the viewing tab to refresh once I add need items from the second tab. I know how to refresh a page with

window.location.reload();

but I would like to know how I can refresh the other page as well when a function is called. Is there a way to refresh all html views with a click?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I fully understood, but it seems like you have two browser tabs (or windows) open and you want one to affect the other.

Since they're separated, they're also running two different app instances, meaning that stuff like `scope.$apply()` just won't affect the other one. Basically, you need to switch from "communication across the app" to "communication across the domain". To achieve that you can use `localStorage` (or a simple cookie, database, file, etc...).

The idea is that one view would check for a certain session variable (say, every two seconds), and force an update and clear that variable in case that variable is set.

The other view, of course, would be in charge of setting that variable to the session once an item is added.

That's probably the simplest approach.

If you want instant changes and constant communication, check out webSockets, but I think it might be an overkill for this.

---

See this simple example:

VIEW: http://jsfiddle.net/1dshqpay/

ADD: http://jsfiddle.net/u7n46Lsk/

They are two completely separate apps/URLs, but adding an item from ADD will show up in VIEW.

*(I couldn't create it here as two snippets as they're sandboxed and not supporting localStorage)*

Comment: Thank you Shomz! this is what i wanted and it works fine. Thanks for quick reply. Hope all the best for you